# How to implement session like stackoverflow?

Tags: http, session, authentication

I'm implementing this kink of login: http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

In this design a new token issued to the user each new login.
So it tells me that I need to
Now I need to implement a session, for this login.

I'd like to implement session like stackoverflow, so people can have session as soon as they entered the site, so they don't must to register.

Any ideas how?

Comment: Consider spending a little more effort in making sure your question is clear.  Did you proof-read this sentence "..so people will can have session without login. but for login there will be ..." and see at least a grammar error and a period in a wrong place.

Comment: @Khnle: give him a break, not everyone is a native English speaker.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a complete stab in the dark here and assume "have a session without a login" is referring to StackOverflow's use of [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), which enables you to share one set of login credentials across websites. The user still has a session, but it's the OpenID provider who does the authentication.